# How to fix 'Expected type 'Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface'. Found 'GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request' error in php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, api, email, mailgun

I want to send an email, so I try to use `guzzlehttp/guzzle` for that, Now this brings me an error.

I try to change the type `Psr7\Request` to 
`\Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface` but it doesn't work too, and it brings me another error

> 'Cannot instantiate interface Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface'.

So I don't know what should I do ?!

```php
public function requestAsync($method, $uri = '', array $options = [])
    {
        $options = $this->prepareDefaults($options);
        // Remove request modifying parameter because it can be done up-front.
        $headers = isset($options['headers']) ? $options['headers'] : [];
        $body = isset($options['body']) ? $options['body'] : null;
        $version = isset($options['version']) ? $options['version'] : '1.1';
        // Merge the URI into the base URI.
        $uri = $this->buildUri($uri, $options);
        if (is_array($body)) {
            $this->invalidBody();
        }
        $request = new Psr7\Request($method, $uri, $headers, $body, $version);
        // Remove the option so that they are not doubly-applied.
        unset($options['headers'], $options['body'], $options['version']);

        return $this->transfer($request, $options);
    }
```

It's brings this error

> ( Expected type 'Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface'. Found
>   'GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request' ).

Comment: It seems like version confilict error. If you're using **guzzle 4.x or 5.x version**, you need instance of `GuzzleHttp\Message\RequestInterface`, but if you're using **guzzle 6.x version**, you need `Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface`. I recommend check the version of guzzle.